# C# Newtonsoft JSON map property to array sub item

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm using Newtonsoft to deserialize JSON data to an object.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "4aa50d01-41bd-45e3-803e-f479a948acf1",
    "referenceNumber": "120064",
    "status": "Application in Progress",
    "borrowers": [
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "type": "BORROWER"
    },
    {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "type": "COBORROWER"
    }
    ],
    "propertyAddress": {
        "zipCodePlusFour": ""
    }
}
```

The borrowers array can have up to 2 items. 1 with `type == "BORROWER"`and the other with `type == "COBORROWER"`

I have a LoanItem class I am deserializing to.

```
public class LoanItem
{
    public string referenceNumber { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can mark the LoanItem property with the JSONProperty attribute but I'm wondering if there is a way I can add an array sub item with a condition.

Something maybe like

```
[JSONProperty("borrowers[WHERE type = 'BORROWER'].name")]
public string BorrowerName { get; set; }

[JSONProperty("borrowers[WHERE type = 'COBORROWER'].name")]
public string CoBorrowerName { get; set; }
```

Is this possible? Can I use the JSONProperty attribute?

Comment: Nope, that's not how it works.

Comment: @JeffMercado so I'll just have to manually parse the JSON and map to my objects?

Comment: You make it sound like it's a bad thing. The `JsonPropertyAttribute` is not designed to do what you want in that way. It's a way to map a simple json property to a .net property. What you're proposing is far more complex than any of the APIs provide. If you want more complex logic, you'll have to be the one to provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new class `Borrower`

```
public class Borrower 
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Update your LoanItem class to this

```
public class LoanItem
{
    public string referenceNumber { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<Borrower> Borrowers {get;set;}
    public string BorrowerName { get { return Borrowers.Where(x=>x.Type == "BORROWER").FirstOrDefault().Name; }
    public string CoBorrowerName { get { return return Borrowers.Where(x=>x.Type == "COBORROWER").FirstOrDefault().Name; } }
}
```

Now you can access the BorrowerName and CoborrowerName

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking so much about how I could use the JSONProperty attribute that I didn't even consider a simple solution.